# how to detect the shape that touch the touch screen

Tags: android

I have received requirement like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MYQicokwmY&feature=plcp I am reviewing this requirement.As per requirement we have to build touch detection like in video link for Android enabled Tablets.

In that video toys (toys with circular, star or rectangle shape) uses Conductive Silicone Sensors with that they are detecting touch on screen & deciding shape of external world object like triangle,circle or a star & further processing the shape.

I have to use same touch detection for android tablets.Can anybody help me to find the way to implement this on Android platform ? Is there any API or framework to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the video around 1:13, they show what I am guessing are some prototypes, the circle has three points, the hexagon too...

My best guess is that the biggest part of the object is non-conductive and only has a few points that are conductive and would actually register as touch points on the screen. The key is that each of them will be different enough that you would be able to recognize them no matter what the orientation is, what the position (and depending on your requirements whether you have several of those objects at the same time on the screen).

You can also play with the area of each conductive points so in your code, you will get the touch information, you can get different [pressure values from the MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29)

Now how you place the conductive points and how many on each shape is completely up to you and would really depend on what your requirements are (recognizing arbitrary shape is not an option...)

Most touch screens would reject the touch if the area is too large (that's palm rejection), so I don't think there are much other ways to do this...